# Retrieve information from plist

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, plist

I'm currently **trying** to make a quiz game on iphone so I saw a tutorial but it seems xcode doesn't understand my plist or  something: my labels are blank when I run it:
in my .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

questionNumber = 0;
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Propriety List" ofType:@"plist"];
if (path) {
NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
self.Question = [tempDict objectForKey:@"Root"];}
currentQuestion = -1;
}


-(void) showNextQuestion {
currentQuestion++;
if (currentQuestion < [self.Question count]) {
    NSDictionary *nextquestion = [self.Question objectAtIndex:currentQuestion];
    self.Answear = [nextquestion objectForKey:@"QuestionAnswear"];
    self.labelQuestionTitle.text = [nextquestion objectForKey:@"QuestionTitle"];
    self.labelAnswearA.text = [nextquestion objectForKey:@"A"];
    self.labelAnswearB.text = [nextquestion objectForKey:@"B"];
    self.labelAnswearC.text = [nextquestion objectForKey:@"C"];
    self.labelAnswearD.text = [nextquestion objectForKey:@"D"];
    self.labelAnswearE.text = [nextquestion objectForKey:@"E"];
    }
else {
    // Game over
    }
}


- (IBAction)buttonPressedA:(id)sender{
if ([self.Answear isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
    numCorrect++;
    NSLog(@"%d", numCorrect);

}
```

Of course I've just put on the related codes and not all of them.
Can someone help please??

Comment: What do you get if you log tempDict?

Comment: How can I do that? (Thank you for the quick answer!)

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",tempDict);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my checkForPlist Method, returns a BOOL and fills an NSDictionary if the plist exists so could be worth running:

```
-(BOOL) checkForPlist
{
    NSString *errorDesc = nil;
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSString *plistPath;
    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                              NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestPlist.plist"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
    }
    NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
    self.plistDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                           propertyListFromData:plistXML
                                           mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                           format:&format
                                           errorDescription:&errorDesc];
    if (!self.plistDictionary) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Plist exists - %@", [self.plistDictionary objectForKey:@"LastUpdated"]);
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: What do I have to put in the .h file? (sorry, I'm sure it's obvious to you but I really just started this)

Comment: No problem - you need to declare an NSDictionary in your .h file called plistDictionary. Everything else is declared in the scope of this method and are unnecessary outside of it.

Comment: Also I would omit spaces in your plist filename - never a good practice!

Comment: There's quite a few bad conventions in this example so it might not be best for someone learning to be using.

Comment: Are there bad examples in mine too? I thought it was ok